# Conversion of .pb file to .ckpt (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have managed to convert a pre-trained .ckpt model to .pb (protobuf) format using this script :

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

# Get the current directory
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print "Current directory : ", dir_path
save_dir = dir_path + '/Protobufs'

graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# Create a session for running Ops on the Graph.
sess = tf.Session()

print("Restoring the model to the default graph ...")
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(dir_path + '/model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(dir_path))
print("Restoring Done .. ")

print "Saving the model to Protobuf format: ", save_dir

#Save the model to protobuf  (pb and pbtxt) file.
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, save_dir, "Binary_Protobuf.pb", False)
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, save_dir, "Text_Protobuf.pbtxt", True)
print("Saving Done .. ")
```

Now, what I want is the vice-verca procedure. How can I load the protobuf file and convert it to .ckpt (checkpoint) format?

I am trying to do that with the following script but it always fails :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse 

# Pass the filename as an argument
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--frozen_model_filename", default="/path-to-pb-file/Binary_Protobuf.pb", type=str, help="Pb model file to import")
args = parser.parse_args()

    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
with tf.gfile.GFile(args.frozen_model_filename, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    #saver=tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:

        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def,
            input_map=None,
            return_elements=None,
            name="prefix",
            op_dict=None,
            producer_op_list=None
        )
        sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)
        saver=tf.train.Saver()
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "path-to-ckpt/model.ckpt")
         print("Model saved to chkp format")
```

I believe that it would be very helpful to have these conversion scripts.

P.S : The weights are already embedded to the .pb file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you only got the graph definition in both of the files, not the frozen model.

```
# This two lines only save the graph as proto file; it doesn't save the variables and their values. 
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, save_dir, "Binary_Protobuf.pb", False)
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, save_dir, "Text_Protobuf.pbtxt", True)
```

frozen graph is obtained using the [freeze_graph file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

Comment: The model is loaded from restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(dir_path)) where the checkpoint (with the weights) is.

Comment: Well! in the second script you didn't load any model, you just imported the graph.   Eventhough you load the model in the first script, it doesn't write the variables into the pb file.

Comment: Ok I changed sess.graph_def to sess.graph in tf.train.write_graph function but same luck.

Comment: You have use the freeze_graph script as i wrote earlier, write_graph doesnt write variables and its values.

Comment: How can I use that in my script? As a python script it requires inputs that I don't have. out.pb, in.pb e.t.c. I only have the checkpoint file.

Comment: inputs for that script are your graph_def file (.pbtxt), checkpoint file(*.ckpt) and the output node of your model.

Comment: I get google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 2:1 : Expected identifier or number. It does not work with these inputs, maybe it requires something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you load a model in pb file, does it can be retrained as a pretrain model. 
I used "tf.global_variables()" to get variables that can be trained, but there have none vars return when I load a pb model .

```
tf.global_variables()
```